# AppEngine: No module named pyasn1.compat.binary

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, webapp2

I keep getting the following error when hitting my AppEngine server:

```
ERROR    2017-09-20 07:16:06,978 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/server/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from controllers import organization_controller
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/server/controllers/organization_controller.py", line 4, in <module>
    import rest_controller as rest
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/server/controllers/rest_controller.py", line 4, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.id_token
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/oauth2/id_token.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.auth import jwt
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/auth/jwt.py", line 53, in <module>
    from google.auth import _service_account_info
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.auth import crypt
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/auth/crypt/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from google.auth.crypt import rsa
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/auth/crypt/rsa.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.auth.crypt import _python_rsa
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/google/auth/crypt/_python_rsa.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/pyasn1/codec/der/decoder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pyasn1.type import univ
  File "/home/dclochri/Projects/react-seed/lib/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyasn1.compat import octets, integer, binary
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1132, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.compat.binary
INFO     2017-09-20 07:16:06,982 module.py:821] default: "OPTIONS /rest/organizations/create HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

My `lib` dir contains `pyasn1` (*v0.3.5*), and `pysasn1` has a `compat` module with `binary.py`. It looks like `pysasn1` is installed as a dependency by the `google-auth` module (see `requirements.txt` below). Dependencies are installed with `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`, as suggested by the [GAE sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes#setup).

My code so far hardly deviates from the sample docs for using Firebase with GAE [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/firebase/firenotes/backend/main.py#L78).

Here are some snippets of what I am using:

Python: 2.7.12

`gcloud` versions:

```
Google Cloud SDK 171.0.0
alpha 2017.09.11
app-engine-python 1.9.60
beta 2017.09.11
bq 2.0.25
core 2017.09.11
gsutil 4.27
```

*requirements.txt*

```
google-auth==1.1.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-toolbelt==0.7.1
```

*rest_controller.py* (snippet)

```
import json
import webapp2
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine

class RestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        """Middleware for all the routes."""
        # Verify the user is authenticated for each request.
        if not self.is_authorized() and self.request.method != 'OPTIONS':
            self.response.set_status(401)
            self.response.write('Unauthorized')
        else:
            super(RestHandler, self).dispatch()

    def get_claims(self):
        """
        Verify the Firebase credentials on the server side via the
        bearer's token.
        """
        auth_headers = self.request.headers['Authorization']
        id_token = auth_headers.split(' ').pop()
        return google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
            id_token, HTTP_REQUEST)

    def get_user_id(self):
        claims = self.get_claims()
        return claims['sub']

    def is_authorized(self):
        """
        Determines if the user is authorized.
        NOTE: We don't have a server-side session, so we are operating based on
        the user's client token. We are basically verifying that the client
        Firebase token is valid by checking it via a server-side request.
        """
        if 'Authorization' in self.request.headers:
            if self.get_claims():
                return True

        return False
```

Directory Structure:

```
/
  lib/
    (deps from requirements.txt here)
  server/
    controllers/
      (controllers here)
    models/
      (models here)
    main.py
  src/
    (client code here - js, css, etc)
  app.yaml
  appengine_config.py
```

This happens on OSX Yosemite and Ubuntu 16.04. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the imports? Is there an issue with the `oauth` module?

Comment: Can you add the entire traceback? How did you install `pyasn1`, it's not in the `requirements.txt`? Is `pyasn1` a pure python lib, with no C extensions (as required by the GAE sandbox)?

Comment: I updated the traceback, and included notes on how it was installed (looks like it is a dependency of `google-auth`). Good question on the C extensions, but it looks like it is a [pure python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyasn1).

Comment: Yep, looks OK. The problem appears to be inside `pyasn1`. What's the content of the `pyasn1/compat` dir?

Comment: Hm, I just tried `import google.oauth2.id_token` with your requirements and it worked just fine. Do you have multiple services in your app?

Comment: Re: Contents of `pysan1/compat`:

 `dateandtime.pyc`, `__init__.py`, `dateandtime.py`, `calling.py`, `octets.py`, `octets.pyc`, `string.py`, `binary.py`, `binary.pyc`, `__init__.pyc`, `string.pyc`, `integer.pyc`, `calling.pyc`

Comment: @Dan, thanks for all your help! Also, only one `app.yaml`, so just one service. I will update the question to show a file structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154904/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-johnnycoder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of thanks to [Dan Cornilescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4495081/dan-cornilescu)! It turns out that my `app.yaml` config was the culprit, specifically the *skip_files* directive.

The bad config looked like:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.git/.*)
- ^.*bin(/.*)?
- ^.*node_modules(/.*)?
- ^.*public(/.*)?
- ^.*src(/.*)?
- ^env$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.pyc$
```

The updated config looks like:

```
# Skip any non-essential files for uploading during deploys.
skip_files:
# Defaults, see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files/
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
# Custom
- ^(.*/)?.*/bin/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/env/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/none_modules/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/public/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/src/.*$
```

So a combo of bad regex and skipping the wrong files broke the local app server, and fixing it got it up and running again.