# Python app can't find Flask-SQLAlchemy when deployed to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a basic REST backend in Python that I am trying to deploy to Google App Engine. However, after following the instructions both [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql), my script cannot import some of my third party libraries.

I've installed all of the libraries in the lib/ directory, I've added 'appengine_config.py' to add `lib` to the path so the libraries should be discovered yet requests always fail with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
(/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/cgi.py:122)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/myapp/myapp/Rest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import flask_sqlalchemy
ImportError: No module named flask_sqlalchemy
```

I have this app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
service: feedback-backend

handlers:
  - url: /*
    script: Rest.py

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: feedbackmysql:us-east4:feedback-mysql

skip_files:
  venv/*
```

and this requirements.txt

```
aniso8601==1.3.0
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
Flask-Restless==0.17.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
mimerender==0.6.0
pep8==1.7.0
PyMySQL==0.7.11
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.14
virtualenv==15.1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

Comment: what is your `requirements.txt` looks like?

Comment: @ykisga FYI requirements.txt isn't part of App Engine's library handling.

Comment: You linked to a standard environment topic and a flexible environment topic, which environment are you using? You should post your complete `app.yaml` file.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or

Comment: @BrettJ It's a standard environment, as far as I can tell. When I'd last done anything with GAE I don't think the different environments were a thing.

Comment: Where is the `lib` dir located relative to the `Rest.py` file?

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't reference the `Rest.py` file in `app.yaml`, you should reference a variable representing a WSGI application defined in `Rest.py`, typically called `app`, like this:  `script: Rest.app`. Donno if related to the import error, tho. See `script` row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table.

Comment: Have you gotten your application running in the `dev_appserver`? That might help you debug

Comment: @DanCornilescu Rest.py and lib/ are both in the root.

Comment: @Charles The dev server fails with a 500 error same as when deployed, but without any console errors.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku: in the root of the app or of the service? (Or do you have all services mixed together right in the app root?)

Comment: A shot in the dark - maybe you should add the `skip_files` default patterns as well? Otherwise it can cause quite obscure failures, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311440/appengine-no-module-named-pyasn1-compat-binary/46413051#46413051

Comment: Is this the 1st import from the `lib` dir in your code or you have others before it which work fine?

Comment: How are you launching the devserver? I never saw a 500 response from it without logs...

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku try adding `--dev_appserver_log_level=debug` when you run local devserver to get code errors